# Windows C API: what's the difference between wincrypt and sspi?

Tags: windows, winapi, cryptoapi

I'm looking at different solutions for windows cryptography, and stumbled across these two libraries. Their header files are `Wincrypt.h` and `Sspi.h`. They both seem to provide encryption and decryption routines: `CryptEncryptMessage` and `EncryptMessage`, they both provide encryption context handles and are really similar. So what do I use them for?

P.S. Also there is CNG, but that is, as I understood, just a successor to wincrypt, which will soon become deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-encryptmessage), the `EncryptMessage` function encrypts a message to provide privacy. `EncryptMessage` allows the application to choose among cryptographic algorithms supported by the chosen mechanism.

**This function is available as a SASL mechanism only.**

For example, if you want use Microsoft's Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) in a Windows Domain environment to send encrypted and signed messages between two entities (in C++).Then you can use `EncryptMessage` .

But `CryptEncryptMessage` is the CAPI2 PKI encryption API.

> Very generically, in absence of context, the `EncryptMessage` is meant
>   to encrypt data for some entity for which you have a cert (only uses
>   crypto) and works offline, the `CryptEncryptMessage` can only be used
>   between a client and a server after they have established a security
>   context using `InitializeSecurityContext/AcceptSecurityContext`.

If you want to learn more, please refer: [Difference between CryptEncryptMessage EncryptMessage(Negotiate)](https://microsoft.public.platformsdk.security.narkive.com/hT57Hjc5/difference-between-cryptencryptmessage-encryptmessage-negotiate)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link you provided points to a website blocked in Russia, so I've only now had a chance to look at it, and it answers all my questions.

Comment: @MorJ Glad to help.